# Is it possible to load HTML into JXBrowser view-source?

Tags: java, jxbrowser

If I have a `Browser` and I call `browser.loadURL("view-source:http://www.example.com);` it goes straight to Chromium's source viewer. Is there a way to do the same thing with the `loadHTML` or `loadData` methods?

Or is there a way to programatically switch it to that view once the page has loaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `view-source` URL prefix is a specific URI scheme that is handled by Chromium itself. Therefore, this prefix can be used with URLs only.

The general purpose of the `loadHTML()` and `loadData()` methods is to load and render the HTML string as a regular web page instead of displaying the source code in the browser. Therefore, there is no straightforward approach to make these methods display the source code instead of rendering the page.

However, you can consider saving the HTML to a temporary file and then load it as shown below:

```
browser.loadURL("view-source:file:///f:\\data\\contents.html");
```